# What was Africa's political system like before European imperialism?

Tags: government, africa

During the Scramble of Africa (1881 - 1914), Europeans basically controlled the entire content. They also implemented their own form of government and culture in many of these places. However, what were the previous forms of political systems like in Africa right before European imperialism?

I'll be more specific.

In the 1870s, France, Britain, and Portugal controlled [some colonies near the coast](https://3ijp5i2qkzo4hq4yrxfteqh-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/t1d.jpg), as they were the easiest to access (by boat). This included the coast of Algeria, the coasts of West Africa, and some coastal regions to the South. But, the majority of inland Africa remained untouched. Those areas were sometimes under rule of a dictator or an empire.

So what were these empires areas like, and how did their government function?

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify on the time frame for this question, I'm looking for information about Africa's political system somewhere around the 1870s, right before the Scramble for Africa happened.

Also, I'm not referring to the nomadic-like tribes that didn't govern themselves under a specific government, but rather the empires and dictators that controlled specific regions.

Comment: +1, but will be more answerable if limited to a certain region of the continent

Comment: @AaronBrick Now that's the problem I'm facing. I don't really know if there's a specific region that I'm looking for... So I'm thinking that it could just be part of an answer. Would that work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kingdoms_in_pre-colonial_Africa

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy That link is good, but is there something that the kingdoms share?

Comment: Africa is a huge continent with many ethincal groups, some of them can not be described in terms of government (hunter/gatherers, nomadic, transhumance).

Comment: @FuzzySquid: It's a list of *kingdoms* only. It excludes the plethora of tribal organizations that sprinkled the landscape. The thing to keep in mind when it comes to Africa is that the latter didn't always have a concept of border or of exclusive control of territory -- i.e they weren't states in the modern sense. One reason there were so many post-colonial wars in Africa is that unit Europeans took over, you could have two or more polities making use of the same territory.

Comment: You've addressed my prior comment - thnk you - but I'm curious why African kingdoms would share something?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Assuming this was directed at me: Kingdoms didn't. But tribal societies did. You'd have one society bring their sheep over on some territory, and move on, and then another moving in a few months later to do the same, and so forth. Each tribe would be centered on a certain area (or not, when nomadic), but towards the edges of these areas there wasn't a clearcut delineation of "this plot of territory is *ours*!" until the Europeans took over. (Or as Proudhon aptly summed it up: property is theft.)

Comment: Africa is a continent that is over three times the size of the United States.  It's regions and peoples vary a great deal.  At present, there are over 50 nations states on the continent, however, before Imperialism and line drawing, there were many more local centers of culture and power.  This question is far too broad.

Comment: I'd hate to see this question closed as we get so few on Africa but, as it stands, it's both too broad and too basic. Can you edit to take  account of Denis' link [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kingdoms_in_pre-colonial_Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kingdoms_in_pre-colonial_Africa)? There are links there to different empires / kingdoms, so it's hard to see what you want which isn't already easily available.

Comment: Africa is not a country. It's like asking what Asia's government was, and at a similar physical scale. If you want to get an idea of the kind of governments were present, a [Comparison of Africa in the years 1880 and 1913](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramble_for_Africa#/media/File:Scramble-for-Africa-1880-1913.png) is useful. We've got Caliphates, Sultanates, Imamates (theocracy), Constitutional Republics, Absolute Monarchies, Constitutional Monarchies, Empires, Autonomous Ottoman Provinces, European Colonies... investigate each one.

Comment: @Everyone So, I think I'll just restart clean and post a new question, and I'll keep all your comments into account. However I'm going to have to do it sometime tomorrow. Thanks!